# how do i map a 2d array in to a matrix of card componants in react js and mui componants

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i am given a 2d array of objects and i need to create form it a matrix of cards [every card will have some text which is taken from the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU5UB.png) and i used the .map fuction but the result for the following array

[[obj1,obj2,obj3],[obj4,obj5,obj6],[obj7,obj8,obj9]]
[is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q3lt.png)

this is my code

```
export defult function Content() {
     return(
       <Grid>
       {DUMMY_DATA.map((obj) => {
         return (
          <Grid item sm={4} sx={{m:1}}>
           <assetCard
           key={obj.id}
           id={obj.id}
           name={obj.text}
          />
         </Grid>
      )
    })}
  </Grid>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MUI column widths are integer values between 1 and 12.

As long as 12 is a multiple of the number of entries in your X-axis (which it is in the example you provided), you can just divide 12 by that number and use "Array.prototype.flatMap" to flatten the resulting list of components:

```
export default function Content() {
     return(
       <Grid>
       {DUMMY_DATA.flatMap(xs => xs.map(x => (
          <Grid item xs={12 / xs.length}>
           <AssetCard
             key={x.id}
             id={x.id}
             name={x.text}
           />
         </Grid>
      )
    )))}
  </Grid>
 );
}
```